# Convert a number to a 32 bit HEX number using web3?

Tags: web3js, javascript

I need to pass the SHA3 function a number, but need it in the format of HEX with the full 32 bits i.e. with leading zeros plus the 0x (e.g. example number 3 ):

web3.sha3("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003")

Is there a function that takes a number e.g. 3 and creates this string/hex number?

Thanks, Ian

Comment: Please note, in your question you are asking to format number in **full 64 bits**, but your actual example has **32 bytes**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ethereumjs-util` has relevant methods: [`setLengthLeft`](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/blob/master/docs/index.md#setlengthleft) and [`bufferToHex`](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/blob/master/docs/index.md#buffertohex):

```
> const util = require('ethereumjs-util');    
> util.bufferToHex(util.setLengthLeft(123, 2))
'0x007b'
> util.bufferToHex(util.setLengthLeft(3, 32))
'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003'
```

Comment: I am facing with `util.setLengthLeft is not a function` error. @max taldykin

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of ways to do this:

### The sprintf way:

How about using https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js ?

then you could do:

```
var hex = '0x' + sprintf('%064d', 3);
// returns 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003`
```

**Together with your code:**

```
var hex = '0x' + sprintf('%064d', 3);
web3.sha3(hex)
```

---

### The pad way:

Alternatively if you are essentially just padding your numbers with zeros, you could extend the `Number` object:

```
Number.prototype.pad = function(size) {
      var s = String(this);
      while (s.length < (size || 2)) {s = "0" + s;}
      return s;
    }
```

*Examples:*

```
(3).pad();  //returns "03"
(3).pad(64);  //returns "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003"
```

**Together with your code:**

```
var hex = '0x' + (3).pad(64);
web3.sha3(hex)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function stringToBytes32(text) {
    let result = utils.toUtf8Bytes(text)
    if (result.length > 32) { throw new Error('String too long') }
    result = utils.hexlify(result);
    while (result.length < 66) { result += '0'; }
    if (result.length !== 66) { throw new Error("invalid web3 implicit bytes32"); }
    return result;
}
```